# Отметить тревогой с комментарием

Tags: поддержка, тревоги

Отметил тревогой [ответ с изображением](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45646264/77764) явно нарушающим правила, отклонили с указанием разъяснить содержание картинки (declined - This is an English-language site. If you think that an image of text in another language is so offensive that it merits a flag, then please explain which text and what it means.).

Но тревога ведь не позволяет указать комментарий?

PS: Необходимо использовать последний пункт (с комментарием) "Требуется вмешательство модератора"?

Comment: Флагнул используя последний пункт и написал туда примерный перевод текста. Посмотрим что будет

Comment: Подождем. Вчера весь день вопрос висел с флагом. В "SO на русском" быстрее реагируют.

Comment: Тоже флаганул для надёжности типа, чем больше флагов, тем быстрее заметят. Интересно, автор действительно не знает, что размещает?

Comment: Картинка уникальная (не из статьи), думаю автор ответа знает русский язык.

Comment: P.S. на той же MSE у меня тревоги неделями висят)

Comment: Добавил ещё одну тревогу.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что enSO - не ruSO.

Comment: @alexolut, проблема в том, что без "Требуется вмешательство модератора" нельзя указать комментарий. И эта проблема не только enSO.

Comment: @alexolut а у нас бывают оскорбительные тексты на украинском или казахском, ситуация та же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно было оставить тревогу для модератора и написать пару слов.

Спасибо вам за внимательность, оскорбительный ответ уже удалили.

Comment: "This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends in 7 days" (:

Comment: @Suvitruf видимо, за этим последовал бан.

Comment: @Suvitruf я там удалил комментарий со ссылкой на соцсеть, чтобы в будущем нельзя было человека найти. Мы ж тут не злопамятные. :)

Comment: Бан на 7 дней за вопрос, заданный год назад? Эффективненько...

Comment: @NickVolynkin ага, вроде в правилах написано, что соц. сети лучше не светить.

Comment: @Qwertiy а на SO срок давности есть по преступлениям? )

Comment: @Suvitruf, _"Last seen Jul 7 at 11:01"_ - что-то мне подсказывает, что он и не заметит эти 7 дней ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy ей на почту сообщение должно было прийти.

Comment: @Suvitruf в том-то и проблема что нету, но это противоречит идеологии банов

Comment: А удалить одну лишь картинку нельзя было?

Comment: @andreymal этот вопрос можно задать модераторам на en.so. Я там не модератор, я не обрабатывал флаг.

Comment: @andreymal но вообще, может и можно было. Если не в ней суть ответа.